# "Connected" UDP sockets, communication in both directions?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming, udp

How do I achieve 2 way communication on a **connected UDP sockets ?**

I can send message from client to server, but can not get a message from server. Here is my code. I think that problem must be in the server side, but I don't know how to solve that problem. I have intentionally removed error checking just to post on SO & keep my post short. I am not receiving any errors on any side.

I can get this program running with **not connected** UDP sockets, but can't with **connected** socket.

**Server.c**

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in me;
  char buffer[1024];

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

  memset(&me, '\0', sizeof(me));
  me.sin_family = AF_INET;
  me.sin_port = htons(8080);
  me.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

  bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&me, sizeof(me));

  recv(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0);
  printf("[+]Data Received: %s\n", buffer);

  strcpy(buffer, "Hello Client\n");
  send(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0);
  printf("[+]Data Send: %s\n", buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

**Client.c**

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in other;
  char buffer[1024];

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

  memset(&other, '\0', sizeof(other));
  other.sin_family = AF_INET;
  other.sin_port = htons(8080);
  other.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

  connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&other, sizeof(other));

  strcpy(buffer, "Hello Server\n");
  send(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0);
  printf("[+]Data Send: %s\n", buffer);

  recv(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0);
  printf("[+]Data Received: %s\n", buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

**Output of Server**

```
[+]Data Received: Hello Server
[+]Data Send: Hello Client
```

**Output of Client**

```
[+]Data Send: Hello Server
// Here it does not receive the message sent by server.
```

Comment: You're not checking the return values of any of these system calls. What do you think will happen when 2 sockets are bound to the same port on the same address on the same machine?

Comment: As I said, I have just removed error checking for this post. I am already checking return values & output is same as I have posted.

Comment: Ah indeed, I read that you had 2 binds.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala How can I solve this problem. Please guide me.

Comment: First of all, please provide all the necessary includes in the post. [mcve] means minimal but complete. Now I need to copypaste all the includes from the manpages even to test this out.

Comment: Added #includes. I am on Mac OS X, if it makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks, works just fine on Linux so far.

Comment: You received messages on both server & client ?

Comment: No, the problem again is that you removed the error handling code so we don't know if you had this same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux, `strace`ing the executable, the server send does say this:

```
sendto(3, "Hello Client\n\0\0\0\310$\220\4J\177\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"...,
       1024, 0, NULL, 0) = -1 EDESTADDRREQ (Destination address required)
```

i.e. the server socket indeed does not know the address it needs to send to. *Any* UDP socket must make the other end of the socket known by either `connect`ing, *or* providing the destination socket address in `sendto`.
`connect` on an UDP socket means just  setting a default address for `send`.

---

To connect the socket on the "server" side, with an unknown party you should use `recvfrom` to find out the socket address of the sending party - then you can `connect` using this address or continue using `sendto`. With `sendto` the same socket can communicate with many different parties concurrently.

---

The TCP server/client sockets are a different case, because *listen/accept* on the server side returns a *new* connected socket that is distinct from the original server socket.

Comment: How do I connect a socket on server side ?

Comment: @BhavinPanara updated. Basically the 'connect` is not a different mechanism on what you said you had working earlier.

Comment: So I have to receive first message on `recvfrom()` on server side, then I can call `connect()` on server side by using the address I have just received, then only I can continue with `send()` & `recv()` for future communication on both side. Am I correct ?

Comment: @BhavinPanara yes

Comment: OK. Thanks for all the info you have given.